# Null WebRootPath in ConfigureServices for Blazor Hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I would like to access the web root path from within `Blazor.Server.Startup.ConfigureServices` in a Blazor Hosted solution.

I have injected `IWebHostEnvironment` into the `Startup` constructor and saved it as a property called "WebHostEnvironment". The problem is that in ConfigureServices, `WebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath` is always null.

I have already verified that:

- `wwwroot` folder exists in my Blazor.Client project.
- `app.UseStaticFiles();` has been called in `Startup.Configure` (not sure if this is necessary, but it is one of the few recommended solutions I've found).

This seems to be a common problem (perhaps WebRootPath is only populated under certain conditions - such as after my app is published/deployed?), however I've been unable to find a clear, definitive answer anywhere and I'm not sure what I can do to obtain the web root path in `ConfigureServices`.

### Use Case

While not directly relevant to the question, I'm trying to obtain the path to my token endpoint so that that I can configure the `TokenUrl` property in a new `OpenApiAuthFlow` for Swashbuckle's `AddSwaggerGen` service. I'd prefer not to have to specify the localhost URL since this will eventually be deployed to a production website. I suppose I could store it in appsettings if needed, but I had hoped not to have to maintain the path there.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "Protected API", Version = "v1"});
        options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:5000/connect/authorize"),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:5000/connect/token"),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"api1", "Demo API - full access"}
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is that help you : https://github.com/Aguafrommars/TheIdServer/blob/24472e68bd476624d4f1246f21a3a257148afa1c/src/IdentityServer/Aguacongas.IdentityServer.Admin/Extensions/MvcBuilderExtensions.cs#L79-L98 ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. If WebRootPath cannot be obtained in `ConfigureServices`, I will do something similar by loading the path from configuration.

Comment: I don't think so, but which configuration file are you trying to load actually ? If you try to load the client configuration file from the server side it's possible but with more code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug but a feature; you just cannot do what you want in `ConfigureServices`.
If you want to access to the *wwwroot* folder put your code in `Configure` method or in a method of `ServiceCollection` you can get a `IServiceProvider` instance such as `.AddTransient`.

**sample**

```cs
services.AddTransient(p =>
{
    var environment = p.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
    var path = environment.WebRootPath;
    return new Stuff(path);
});
```

Comment: You mention it should be accessible from `Configure`, but when I inject IWebHostEnvironment into `Startup.Configure`, the `WebRootPath` is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "wwwroot" folder to your Blazor server project (assuming you have the standard 3 projects in your solution - client, server, and shared). The folder itself can be empty, but it needs to be there, otherwise the WebRootPath will be null.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include details of _how_ they would do this? That will make this a more useful answer, with more concrete steps for readers to follow. Remember, developers with this question are likely new to Blazor and will need more explicit guidance.